# Websocket Frame Length Size & Bandwidth

Tags: html, websocket

I'm a bit worried about my chat app in my game and how the bandwidth will be consumed.

For example, I'm not using binary websockets and I heard going binary can be a bandwidth saver, but it's really not worth it right now to switch over at this current time. So I do apologize for that.

In any case, I have a question regarding this gif I made:
[image]

As you can see, sending a simple private message with my app uses a total of 113 in length. (25+42+46). How do I measure the bandwidth for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Average number of sent messages TIMES average message length in bytes) DIVIDED BY time in seconds.

You should get bytes per second.

Binary messages might save something, but if you plan to send short text messages, it might not be worth doing.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yeah, most of the messages from the socket game server are less than 100 in length. I don't think I'll make the move to binary. I don't really see a need.  Appreciate your help. I hope in the future chrome devs can add a bandwidth monitor for websockets. That would be amazing.